# AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials when trying to get Bearer token from postman

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint, postman

My Concept is to integrate Sharepoint with my Java Application. For that i am writing an API.

I checked many sites and visited many questions from our stackoverflow site. And i had done it for more than one day. But i am not able to recover from this issue. So i am asking a question.

I create One application from https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList

And i got Application ID & Secret Key. From this, i got Bearer Realm token using Postman App. https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/client.svc and i got result which is attached here.[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vywyh.png). From here i got Bearer Realm. And then i tried to get Bearer Token from this URL using POST method. https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/a00b84b6-6268-499a-9945-7f16832eb8c4/tokens/OAuth/2 But it is throwing Error: "invalid_client". I had attached the screenshot. [image]
Please share some ideas according to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the App in the Azure AD v2 endpoint, and then you are trying to use an ACS endpoint - those (AAD and ACS) are 2 different things. Please see this Q&A, it summarizes a couple of options that you have: [Sharepoint API Headless Obtaining Access Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302399/sharepoint-api-headless-obtaining-access-tokens/44307515#44307515)